# jquery equal to function form validation

Tags: jquery, forms, validation, equals

I have been working on some form validation in jQuery. Everything was going nicely and then I realised I need to do a password and confirm password validation method. I have so far:

```
    'dotwPassword': function () {

        var info = $('.dotwPassword');
        var ele = $('#dotwPassword');

        if (ele.val().length < 6) {
            jVal.errors = true;
            info.removeClass('dotwCorrect').addClass('dotwError');
            ele.removeClass('dotwNormal').addClass('dotwWrong');
        } else {
            info.removeClass('dotwError').addClass('dotwCorrect');
            ele.removeClass('dotwWrong').addClass('dotwNormal');
        }
    },

    'dotwConpassword': function () {

        var info = $('.dotwConpassword');
        var ele = $('#dotwConpassword');


        if (ele.val().length < 6) {
            jVal.errors = true;
            info.removeClass('dotwCorrect').addClass('dotwError');
            ele.removeClass('dotwNormal').addClass('dotwWrong');
        } else {
            info.removeClass('dotwError').addClass('dotwCorrect');
            ele.removeClass('dotwWrong').addClass('dotwNormal');
        }
    },
```

Can anyone show me how to add in a match for password on conpassword so these 2 fields have to be the same in order to proceed and send the form?

Thanks in advance

Richard

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't you just need to add the following test to both functions:

```
if ($('#dotwPassword').val() != $('#dotwConpassword').val()) {
   // add error stuff here
} else {
   // add correct stuff here
}
```

You could add that to the same if test you already have:

```
if (ele.val().length < 6 || ele.val() != $('#dotwConpassword').val()) {
```

Or handle it separately.